# Cabal using older version when newer is installed

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, version, cabal

I've just installed and updated cabal, but it is still using the original version (1.16.0.2) instead of the updated 1.22.4.0. The commands I have run, after installation through apt-get:

`$ cabal update
$ cabal install cabal-install cabal`

This built and installed the new version of cabal-install and cabal as was expected, but when I do `cabal --v` it still prints:

`$ cabal --v
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library`

What could be wrong here? My $PATH variable is:

`$ echo $PATH
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin:/home/user/.rvm/bin`

and cabal is located:

`$ which cabal
/usr/bin/cabal`

A `sudo find / -name *cabal*` yielded:

`$ sudo find / -name *cabal*
/usr/bin/cabal
/usr/share/doc/cabal-install
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/cabal.vim
/etc/bash_completion.d/cabal
/var/cache/apt/archives/cabal-install_1.16.0.2-2_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cabal-install.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cabal-install.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/cabal-install.md5sums
/home/user/Downloads/pandoc-1.14.0.3/pandoc.cabal
/home/user/.cabal
/home/user/.cabal/bin/cabal
/home/user/.cabal/share/doc/cabal-install-1.22.4.0
/home/user/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/cabal-install
/home/user/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/cabal-install/1.22.4.0/cabal-install-1.22.4.0.tar.gz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cabal installs the new cabal version under

```
/home/user/.cabal/bin
```

Thus, you either have to directly call `/home/user/.cabal/bin/cabal` or add

```
/home/user/.cabal/bin
```

to your path.

`/usr/bin/cabal` is the version packaged by Debian.